# More efficient way to send data from php to js

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, vtigercrm

I have a widget that has a form in it. my goal is that when the submit button is pressed some data gets send to php which will run a function to get data form db. I need the data in the js file so right now i jsonify the data en put it in a file called data.json. from that file i get the data with jquery.ajax().

My question is: How can i make this more efficiant?

.php

```
<?php

chdir('/var/www/html/vtigercrm');
require_once('include/utils/utils.php');

if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])){
    $filterdData = getChartData($_POST['id'], $_POST['maxAmount'], $_POST['minAmount']);

    $file = fopen("/var/www/html/vtigercrm/include/data.json", "w");
    fwrite($file, json_encode($filterdData));
    fclose($file);
}

function getChartData($product_id, $maxAmount=NULL, $minAmount=NULL){
    global $adb;

    $maxAmountQuery = "";
    $minAmountQuery = "";

    if(!is_null($maxAmount) && $maxAmount != ""){
        $maxAmountQuery = " AND i.quantity <= " . $maxAmount;
    }
    if(!is_null($minAmount) && $minAmount != ""){
        $minAmountQuery = " AND i.quantity >= " . $minAmount;
    }

    $sales = $adb->run_query_allrecords("SELECT c.modifiedtime, i.quantity, i.listprice, i.discount_percent, i.discount_amount, CONCAT(q.quote_no, ' ', q.subject) AS quotename " .
                        "FROM vtiger_inventoryproductrel i " .
                        "INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity c ON c.crmid = i.id " .
                        "INNER JOIN vtiger_quotes q ON q.quoteid = i.id " .
                        "WHERE q.quotestage = 'Delivered' AND i.productid = " . $product_id .
                        $maxAmountQuery . $minAmountQuery .
                        " ORDER BY c.modifiedtime ASC");

    //Calculate price after discount
    $salesCalculated = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($sales); $i++){
        $tmpdate = explode(" ", $sales[$i][0]);

        $salesCalculated[$i][0] = $tmpdate[0];
        $salesCalculated[$i][1] = $sales[$i][1];

        if($sales[$i][3] == "" && $sales[$i][4] == ""){
            $salesCalculated[$i][2] = $sales[$i][2] * 1;
        }elseif($sales[$i][3] == ""){
            $salesCalculated[$i][2] = $sales[$i][2] - ($sales[$i][4] / $sales[$i][1]);
        }elseif($sales[$i][4] == ""){
            $salesCalculated[$i][2] = $sales[$i][2] - ($sales[$i][2] / 100 * $sales[$i][3]);
        }

        $salesCalculated[$i][3] = $sales[$i][5];
    }

    //Add element for every item
    $count = 0;
    $salesScatter = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($salesCalculated); $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < $salesCalculated[$i][1]; $j++){
            $salesScatter[$count] = [];
            $salesScatter[$count][0] = $salesCalculated[$i][0];
            $salesScatter[$count][1] = $salesCalculated[$i][2];
            $salesScatter[$count][2] = $salesCalculated[$i][3];
            $count++;
        }
    }

    //Get average and split date
    $count = 0;
    $mydata = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($salesScatter); $i++){
        $sum = 0;
        $num = 0;

        for($j = 0; $j < count($salesScatter); $j++){
            if($salesScatter[$i][0] == $salesScatter[$j][0]){
                $sum += $salesScatter[$j][1];
                $num++;
            }
        }

        $mydata[$count] = [];

        $mydata[$count][0] = explode("-", $salesScatter[$i][0]);
        $mydata[$count][1] = $salesScatter[$i][1];
        $mydata[$count][2] = $sum / $num;
        $mydata[$count][3] = $salesScatter[$i][2];
        $count++;
    }

    return $mydata;
}

function getProductSales($product_id){
    global $adb;

    $mydata = getChartData($product_id);

    $file = fopen("/var/www/html/vtigercrm/include/data.json", "w");
    fwrite($file, json_encode($mydata));
    fclose($file);

    //Data to send to Smarty
    $highest = 0;
    $average = 0;
    $lowest = $mydata[0][1];

    for($i = 0; $i < count($mydata); $i++){
        if($mydata[$i][1] > $highest){
            $highest = $mydata[$i][1];
        }

        $average += $mydata[$i][1];

        if($mydata[$i][1] < $lowest){
            $lowest = $mydata[$i][1];
        }
    }
    $average /= count($mydata);

    $product = $adb->run_query_record("SELECT CONCAT(product_no, ' (', productname, ')'), unit_price " .
                            "FROM vtiger_products WHERE productid = " . $product_id);

    $product_details = [ 'name'=>$product[0], 'unit'=>$product[1], 'highest'=>$highest, 'average'=>$average, 'lowest'=>$lowest];

    return $product_details;
}
 ?>
```

.tpl

```
{strip}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'include/getProductSales.php',
                data: { id: {php}echo $_GET['record'];{/php} ,
                    maxAmount:$("#maxAmount").val(), 
                    minAmount:$("#minAmount").val() 
                },
                complete: function(){
                    drawChart();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="resources/priceChart.js"></script>

<form>
    <table class="table table-bordered equalSplit detailview-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="blockHeader" colspan="4">
                    <img class="cursorPointer alignMiddle blockToggle  hide" src="layouts/vlayout/skins/alphagrey/images/arrowRight.png" data-mode="hide" data-id="31">
                    <img style="display: inline;" class="cursorPointer alignMiddle blockToggle" src="layouts/vlayout/skins/alphagrey/images/arrowDown.png" data-mode="show" data-id="31">
                    Details
                </th>    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Product</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium">{$PRODUCT['name']}</td>

                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">List Price</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium">{$PRODUCT['unit']}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Highest Price</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium">{$PRODUCT['highest']}</td>

                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Max. Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium"><input type="text" name="maxAmount" id="maxAmount"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Average Price</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium">{$PRODUCT['average']}</td>

                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Min. Amount</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium"><input type="text" name="minAmount" id="minAmount"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px">Lowest Price</label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium">{$PRODUCT['lowest']}</td>

                <td class="fieldLabel medium">
                    <label class="muted pull-right marginRight10px"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldValue medium"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Filter"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<style>
    #chart_div{
        margin: 20px 0px;
        background-color: white;
        min-height: 450px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
        box-shadow:         4px 4px 15px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    }

</style>

<div id="chart_div" ></div>
{/strip}
```

.js

```
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//check window size
if (document.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener("resize", drawChart);
}
else if (document.attachEvent)
{
    window.attachEvent("onresize", drawChart);
}
else
{
    window.resize = drawChart;
}

function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "include/getChartdata.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var mydata = $.parseJSON(jsonData);

    console.log(mydata);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("datetime", "Date");
    data.addColumn("number", "Price");
    data.addColumn({type : "string", role : "tooltip"});

    data.addColumn("number", "Price (Average)");
    data.addColumn({type : "string", role : "tooltip"});

    var s = mydata.length;

    if(s == 0){
        alert("There is no data in the range you selected. Please select another range.");
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < s; i++ ){
        data.addRow([new Date(mydata[i][0][0], mydata[i][0][1]-1, mydata[i][0][2]), mydata[i][1], mydata[i][3] + " " + mydata[i][1], mydata[i][2], 'Average of : ' + mydata[i][2]]);
    }

    var min = new Date(mydata[0][0][0], mydata[0][0][1]-1, mydata[0][0][2]);
    min.setDate(min.getDate() - 7);
    var max = new Date(mydata[s-1][0][0], mydata[s-1][0][1]-1, mydata[s-1][0][2]);
    max.setDate(max.getDate() + 7);

    var options = {
        chartArea:{width:"80%",height:"70%"},
        hAxis: {
            title: "Date",
            viewWindow: {
                min: min,
                max: max
            },
            gridlines: {
                count: -1,
                units: {
                    days: {
                        format: ["MMM dd"]
                    },
                }
            },
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Price",
            minValue: 0
        },
        legend: "none",
        series: {
            0: {
                pointSize: 10,
                dataOpacity: 0.6,
                pointShape: "diamond"
            },
            1: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                color: "#509C49",
                pointSize: 2
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you saving this file? Change $_POST to $_GET and make your urls and user input send parameters to the PHP. Then PHP runs the query to get the data from the DB, encodes it through JSON and returns to user, no saving into file needed. I see you're using jQuery, so $.getJSON should work for you just fine. You're writing stuff you don't need. I'm in a hurry i will explain better if needed when tonight.

Comment: thnx for answering. Could you answer the following when you have the time: how would i get the variable to the js file? because if i change the POST to GET i will have the variables in the .tpl file script tags and not in the function that draws the chart. in php i need to echo the data right?